# Error using arrayList passed in Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I am passing an arrayList to another activity using this in my main activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PairedDevices.class);
i.putExtra("arrayListPaired", arrayListpaired);
startActivity(i);
```

To be passed to an actvity called PairedDevices where I want to display that array list.  Here is the PairedDevices class:

```
public class PairedDevices extends Activity {
    ListView listViewPaired;
    ArrayList<String> pairedDevices = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("arrayListPaired");
    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_paired_devices);
        listViewPaired = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewPaired);

        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(PairedDevices.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pairedDevices);
        listViewPaired.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }
}
```

It is crashing and I am getting the following stacktrace, Any advice on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated!:

```
10-28 02:04:10.101  25536-25536/my.obd2connector E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: my.obd2connector, PID: 25536
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{my.obd2connector/my.obd2connector.PairedDevices}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at my.obd2connector.PairedDevices.<init>(PairedDevices.java:17)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2222)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Move this line: pairedDevices = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("arrayListPaired"); to onCreate()

Comment: Thank you sir, will mark as answer.  It's getting late ;)

Comment: pairedDevices = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("arrayListPaired") i also told to u but u r not undersgtand

Comment: I see now it just needed to be in the start because it cant be initiated at the on create of the window.  Thanks for the help everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in `onCreate`

```
pairedDevices = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("arrayListPaired");
```

like this

```
public class PairedDevices extends Activity 
{
    ListView listViewPaired;
    ArrayList<String> pairedDevices = null; 
    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_paired_devices);
         listViewPaired = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewPaired);
         pairedDevices = (ArrayList<String>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("arrayListPaired");
         listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(PairedDevices.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pairedDevices);
         listViewPaired.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

place this code in onCreate();

```
ArrayList<String> pairedDevices = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("arrayListPaired");
```

Comment: `getIntent()` works only in `onCreate():` ?!!? you can use that after onCreate method like `onResume` , `onStart`

Comment: @shayanpourvatan you are right. I mean that it will not work outside OnCreate(). Anyway thanks, I will edit my answer.

Comment: In general terms, it won't work before the onCreate.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this code to solve your error

Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PairedDevices.class);

i.putStringArrayListExtra("arrayListPaired", arrayListpaired);

startActivity(i);

And This code replace in PairedDevices file

ArrayList<`String`> pairedDevices = (ArrayList<`String`>) getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("arrayListPaired");